# Dynamically Changing Report DataSource to point at different Databases

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2

We've been developing a web forms project, which can cater for multiple companies via url parameters.

Each company has their own database.

It is a requirement that if Company "A" logs in and runs a report that it looks at their data, we also want the report to be accessible via SSRS directly without having to specify the company name as a report parameter via SSRS itself. For one thing we don't want these companies to see each others data!

My bosses are adamant that they don't want to have multiple sets of reports deployed for each company.

I've tried using some Dynamic SQL and a hidden report parameter to change the database context, which works fine within the asp.Net site, but when accessing it directly it doesn't work to the requirements understandably.

I'd have preferred either that the asp.net site had the reports as part of the project so that each were available at all times (however we sell SSRS as part of the "package"), or to have preferred that each company had their own folder/set of reports.

I've been involved this development rather late in the game. I have a feeling that what is required isn't possible.

Does anyone have any idea's on how to make this work? or can point me in the right direction?

Thanks,

David

Answer (score 0):

You can parameterize parts of the connection string using report parameters. See the section "Expression-Based Connection Strings" here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156450.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We've got it working with that approach. I've probably not been clear enough in my post. The requirement is to have report "invoice" available for all customers (1-10), to be accessable via the asp.net site and by SSRS, without the user having to specifiy what company they are.

Comment: Can you infer the database from the authenticated username somehow?

Comment: That might be possible, however that would require each and every report having the domain translation. It would be hard to test, and difficult to maintain if we get 10+ clients.

Comment: How about put the domain mapping in an second data source, and use the Lookup function to map it into the connection string for the primary data source.

Comment: I wasn't aware that you could use the connection string of a data source for other purposes. How could that be done?

Comment: I'm not saying you should use the connection string for another purpose, I'm suggesting you may be able to centralize the domain-to-database-name mapping in a secondary database, and combine a Lookup into that database with the current user's domain as input, and evaluate that within an expression-based connection string to connect to the proper database for that user.  That would relieve you of having to maintain a copy of the domain-to-db-name mapping in every RDL file.  This is largely speculation on my part, I haven't done this myself.

Comment: Yes! I realised that on my way home last night.